# nodejs handeling a select form element

Tags: node.js, forms, express, select

I have a (probably very stupid) question. 
I have a form I submit to my nodeJS server with Express. 
This works perfectly with text inputs and radiobuttons, but now I have to add a select.
The server does not give an error but the select is not parsed properly.

my code:

```
<select id="chooselang">
<option value="nl" name="language">NL</option>
<option value="en" name="language">EN</option>
</select>
```

and my server looks like this:

```
app.post('/settings', function(req, res){
// Fill JSON array with new settings
var myData = {
    ,name  : req.body.name
            ,mail : req.body.email
            ,language : req.body.language
    ,location: req.body.location
}
// Write to JSON file
fs.writeFile(configfilepath, JSON.stringify(myData, null, 4), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        res.send(500);
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            res.redirect('back');
        }, 2000)
    }
}); 
});
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your `<select>` needs a `name` attribute...

Comment: Yup that was it! I initially did it the way you suggested but forgot to restart the server so I thought it did not work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

Probably you will need to add a `name` attribute in your `select` and use that to capture the values.

Also, only one of the `option` values will be sent to the server, so there is no point in assigning `name` to each one of the options, if that was your intention.